# Type of join used when join condition is where clause

Tags: sql, join

I would like to get a detailed information about what type of join is used 
for this query.

```
select table1.column, table2.column
from table1, table2
where table1.key = table2.key
and (some filter conditions)
```

Comment: Use explicit `join` syntax and you won't have to worry about such details.

Comment: when you do that, you do an INNER JOIN.

Comment: i am using Oracle DB...so is this same as inner join...i.e select table1.column,table2.column from table1 inner join table2 where table1.key=table2.key and(some filter conditions)

Answer (score 3):

When you use a notation like this:

`table1,table2` you're building a potentially `CROSS JOIN` but you have put in `WHERE` clause the condition `table1.key = table2.key` so your `CROSS JOIN` becomes an `INNER JOIN`.

I advice you to use an explicit notation about JOIN, instead of use comma like your query write this:

```
select table1.column, table2.column
from table1
inner join table2
on table1.key = table2.key
where (some filter conditions)
```

In this way you exactely know which `JOIN` you want to use and SQL parser, if you miss some clause (as ON) warns you

Comment: hy Joe...thanx ...but when i take the count of records for both the queries itz not matching

Comment: @user3514648: Please post your query about COUNT

Comment: @user3514648: Joe's answer is correct and his query does exactly what your query does. So this must be a mistake on your part.